# Is there a word such as женат and замужем for homosexuals?

Tags: лексикон

Is there a word such as `женат` and `замужем` for homosexuals? Which would they use (in case they married in another country and came to Russia afterwards)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's hard to imagine exact replacement for *женат* or *замужем* in homosexual case. I think most neutral construction (for both men and women) would use a verb:

> Мы поженились.

More elaborated answer: https://russian.stackexchange.com/a/8158/4630